# Unir dos queries

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo dos queries que me generan datos para venta de maquinas:

**query 1:**

```
SELECT
    Dia,
    SUM(CASE WHEN EstadoLectura = 'LEIDO' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Cantidad de Maquinas',
    SUM(CASE WHEN EstadoLectura = 'LEIDO' THEN Total ELSE 0 END) AS 'Total Maquinas'
FROM Reporte_maquinas
WHERE Dia <> 0
GROUP BY Dia
ORDER BY Dia
```

La informacion que genera:

| Dia | Cantidad de Maquinas | Total Maquinas |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 6 | 16 | 29287 |
| 7 | 6 | 14235 |
| 8 | 63 | 257796 |
| 9 | 51 | 229244 |
| 12 | 324 | 1843430 |
| 13 | 163 | 738186 |
| 14 | 291 | 1897771 |
| 15 | 177 | 490320 |
| 16 | 18 | 29272 |
| 17 | 12 | 13318 |
| 18 | 67 | 171970 |
| 19 | 746 | 2527861 |
| 20 | 267 | 1933228 |
| 21 | 3130 | 12975689 |

**query 2:**

```
SELECT
    Dia_factura,
    SUM(CASE WHEN EstadoLectura = 'LEIDO' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '# Cantidad de Maquinas',
    SUM(CASE WHEN EstadoLectura = 'LEIDO' THEN Total ELSE 0 END) AS '# Total Maquinas'
FROM Reporte_maquinas
WHERE Dia_factura <> 0
GROUP BY Dia_factura
ORDER BY Dia_factura
```

Informacion generada:

| Dia_factura | # Cantidad de Maquinas | # Total Maquinas |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 9 | 12 | 56728 |
| 12 | 38 | 187674 |
| 13 | 151 | 939645 |
| 14 | 82 | 239753 |
| 15 | 155 | 552393 |
| 19 | 83 | 176491 |
| 20 | 77 | 318991 |
| 21 | 1860 | 10648261 |

El asunto es que debo unificar las queries para generar solo un resultado, similar a esto:

| Dia | Cantidad de Maquinas | Total Maquinas | # Cantidad de Maquinas | # Total Maquinas |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6 | 16 | 29287 | 0 | 0 |
| 7 | 6 | 14235 | 0 | 0 |
| 8 | 63 | 257796 | 0 | 0 |
| 9 | 51 | 229244 | 12 | 56728 |
| 12 | 324 | 1843430 | 38 | 187674 |
| 13 | 163 | 738186 | 151 | 939645 |
| 14 | 291 | 1897771 | 82 | 239753 |
| 15 | 177 | 490320 | 155 | 552393 |
| 16 | 18 | 29272 | 0 | 0 |
| 17 | 12 | 13318 | 0 | 0 |
| 18 | 67 | 171970 | 0 | 0 |
| 19 | 746 | 2527861 | 83 | 176491 |
| 20 | 267 | 1933228 | 77 | 318991 |
| 21 | 3130 | 12975689 | 1860 | 10648261 |

Trate usando esta query, pero no genera los valores correspondientes y se me acaban las ideas:

```
SELECT
    Dia,
    SUM(CASE WHEN EstadoLectura = 'LEIDO' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Cantidad de Maquinas',
    SUM(CASE WHEN EstadoLectura = 'LEIDO' THEN Total ELSE 0 END) AS 'Total Maquinas',
    SUM(CASE WHEN EstadoLectura = 'LEIDO' AND Dia_factura <> 0 AND Dia_factura IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '# Cantidad de Maquinas',
    SUM(CASE WHEN EstadoLectura = 'LEIDO' AND Dia_factura <> 0 AND Dia_factura IS NOT NULL THEN Total ELSE 0 END) AS '# Total Maquinas'
FROM Reporte_maquinas
WHERE Dia <> 0
GROUP BY Dia
ORDER BY Dia
```

Espero me puedan ayudar.

Comment: Los campos Dia y Dia_factura son campos distintos. y quieres al final realizar el sum de todo, agrupándolo todo en el campo Dia?

Comment: Basicamente asi me lo pidieron. La idea es hacer coincidir lo que hay en Dia y Dia_factura. `Dia` contempla todas las maquinas compradas, y 'Dia_factura', contempla justamente lo anterior, sumado a las generadas con factura. Si te fijas en las dos tablas que añadi de ejemplo, `Dia_factura` no tiene dias distintos a `Dia`. No se si se entiende.

Comment: En lugar de los dos sum de Dia_factura, puedes plantear con dos subconsultas y agrupando primero por Dia_factura group_by Dia_factura y relacionando en el where dia_factura = dia.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No puedes unir las dos consultas, por que según entiendo una misma fila podría tener un `dia` y otro distinto en `Dia_factura`, lo cual requeriría expandir esa fila en dos. Lo que si puedes hacer es unir ambas consultas y luego sí agrupar por día:

```
SELECT  T.Dia,
        SUM(T.cant_maquinas_d)     as 'Cantidad de Maquinas'
        SUM(T.total_maquinas_d)    as 'Total Maquinas'
        SUM(T.cant_maquinas_f)     as '# Cantidad de Maquinas'
        SUM(T.total_maquinas_f)    as '# Total Maquinas'
        FROM (
            SELECT  Dia_factura as Dia,
                    0,                                                              AS cant_maquinas_d,
                    0,                                                              AS total_maquinas_d,
                    SUM(CASE WHEN EstadoLectura = 'LEIDO' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)        AS cant_maquinas_f,
                    SUM(CASE WHEN EstadoLectura = 'LEIDO' THEN Total ELSE 0 END)    AS total_maquinas_f
                    FROM Reporte_maquinas
                    WHERE Dia_factura <> 0
                    GROUP BY Dia_factura

            UNION ALL

            SELECT  Dia,
                    SUM(CASE WHEN EstadoLectura = 'LEIDO' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)         AS cant_maquinas_d,
                    SUM(CASE WHEN EstadoLectura = 'LEIDO' THEN Total ELSE 0 END)     AS total_maquinas_d,
                    0                                                                AS cant_maquinas_f,
                    0                                                                AS total_maquinas_f
                    FROM Reporte_maquinas
                    WHERE Dia <> 0
                    GROUP BY Dia
        ) AS T
        GROUP BY T.Dia
```

Comment: Estimado, muchas gracias por todo. Probe tu query y funciono perfectamente!

Answer (score 2):

una forma de solucionarlo (no se si es la mas optima) es preparar tu tabla y luego volverla a procesar realizando las sumas.

Con un subquery puedes ligar los días de factura con los días normales. Una ves teniendo tu tabla lista, puedes realizar las sumas agrupando por día.

También dentro de la suma validamos si el campo es nulo ya que puede presentarse que no tengas datos en días_factura ciertos dias

```
SELECT Dia,
SUM(Maquinas) AS 'Cantidad de Maquinas',
SUM(Total_Maquinas) AS 'Total Maquinas',
SUM(ISNULL(N_Maquinas,0)) AS '# Cantidad de Maquinas',
SUM(ISNULL(N_Total_Maquinas,0)) AS '# Total Maquinas'
FROM (
    SELECT
        Dia,
        (CASE WHEN EstadoLectura = 'LEIDO' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Maquinas',
        (CASE WHEN EstadoLectura = 'LEIDO' THEN Total ELSE 0 END) AS 'Total_Maquinas'
    FROM Reporte_maquinas AS T0
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT
            Dia_factura,
            (CASE WHEN EstadoLectura = 'LEIDO' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'N_Maquinas',
            (CASE WHEN EstadoLectura = 'LEIDO' THEN Total ELSE 0 END) AS 'N_Total_Maquinas'
        FROM Reporte_maquinas
        ) AS T1 ON T0.Dia = T1.Dia_factura
    WHERE Dia <> 0
)
GROUP BY Dia
ORDER BY Dia
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes probar con esta consulta, realizando las dos subconsultas.

```html
SELECT
    Dia,
    SUM(CASE WHEN EstadoLectura = 'LEIDO' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Cantidad de Maquinas',
    SUM(CASE WHEN EstadoLectura = 'LEIDO' THEN Total ELSE 0 END) AS 'Total Maquinas',
    SELECT (SUM(CASE WHEN EstadoLectura = 'LEIDO' AND Dia_factura <> 0 AND Dia_Factura = Dia AND Dia_factura IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) GROUP BY Dia_Factura) AS '# Cantidad de Maquinas',
    SELECT (SUM(CASE WHEN EstadoLectura = 'LEIDO' AND Dia_factura <> 0 AND Dia_Factura = Dia AND Dia_factura IS NOT NULL THEN Total ELSE 0 END) GROUP BY Dia_Factura) AS '# Total Maquinas'
FROM Reporte_maquinas
WHERE Dia <> 0
GROUP BY Dia
ORDER BY Dia
```